# How can I compare Database I/O load across SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server

We are preparing to migrate many of our SQL Servers to the cloud. I want to find a logical way to redistribute the databases on the new virtual servers. One factor I want to consider is how 'busy" the database is. My thought was to take the information from the dm_io_virtual_stats DMV as shown below to get a number I can compare across servers. Essentially it takes the sum of num_of_bytes_read and sum_of_bytes_written divided by the sample_ms to get an idea of the average I/O of each database since the last time the system was started. I'm running this code across several servers, so dividing by the sample_ms should make it a valid comparison against different machines, I hope. I've read several articles on this DMV, but none address this particular use case.

```
BEGIN

declare @DatabaseId as int
declare @FileId as int
declare @DatabaseStart as datetime2
declare @BytesIn bigint
declare @BytesOut as bigint
declare @BytesOnDisk as bigint

create table #FileInfo (
  ServerName varchar(128),
  DatabaseName varchar(128),
  UpTime bigint,
  InputBytes float,
  OutputBytes float,
  BytesOnDisk bigint )

DECLARE FileCursor CURSOR FOR
select database_id, file_id
from sys.master_files

open FileCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM FileCursor into @DatabaseId, @FileId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      select @BytesIn = num_of_bytes_read, 
             @BytesOut = num_of_bytes_written, 
             @BytesOnDisk = size_on_disk_bytes, 
             @DatabaseStart = sqlserver_start_time
      from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(@DatabaseId, @FileId),
           sys.dm_os_sys_info

      insert into #FileInfo values ( @@SERVERNAME, 
                                     db_name(@DatabaseId),  
                                     datediff(second, @DatabaseStart, getdate()), 
                                     @Bytesin, 
                                     @BytesOut, 
                                     @BytesOnDisk )
      FETCH NEXT FROM FileCursor into @DatabaseId, @FileId
   END;
CLOSE FileCursor
DEALLOCATE FileCursor

select ServerName, 
       DatabaseName, 
       (SUM((InputBytes + OutputBytes) / UpTime))[AvgBytesPerSec], 
       SUM(BytesOnDisk)[DatabaseSize]
from #FileInfo 
where UpTime > 0 
group by ServerName, DatabaseName
order by ServerName, DatabaseName

Drop table #FileInfo
END
GO
```

Comment: Consider adding SUM(num_if_reads_num_of_writes) since I/O rate is also a consideration.  I think disk performance counter collection is a better tool for this task because the average since the instance was started will hide activity peaks and valleys that may be a consideration.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I know that it is a very rough average especially if the server has been up for a long time. I also learned that the sample_ms is only an int and goes negative after a while :( I wound up calculating seconds since sqlserver_start_time in the sys.dm_os_sys_info DMV to use as the denominator.